# SLIM and TWIG error

Tags: twig, slim-3

I have this error

> **An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template**
>   ("Named route does not exist for name: auth.signup").

This is the TWIG code for the NAV template

```
<li><a href="{{ path_for('auth.signup') }}">Sign up</a></li>
```

This is the ROUTE definition

```
$app->group('/auth', function () {

    $this->get('/signup', 'App\Controllers\Auth\AuthController:getSignup')
         ->setName('auth.signup');

    $this->post('/signup', 'App\Controllers\Auth\AuthController:postSignup');


    $this->get('/signin', 'App\Controllers\Auth\AuthController:getSignin')
         ->setName('auth.signin');

    $this->post('/signin', 'App\Controllers\Auth\AuthController:postSignin');
});
```

I'm stumped because the SIGNIN template code works just fine

```
<form action="{{ path_for('auth.signup') }}" method="post" autocomplete="off">
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. I'm new to this and I thought was being cleaver... to cleaver for my own good. I had my route collections in separate files and would only load the route asked for. Seems that TWIG needs the containers that hold PATH_FOR values as well. I put all the routes in a single file and it works fine